# make keyboard shortcut screenshot include cursor

Tags: macos, mojave

The cmd shift 3 screenshot doesn't include the mouse cursor.

How can I make ***it*** (as in, cmd+shift+3) capture the mouse position also?

Comment: https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/03/13/screenshots-mouse-cursor-mac/ explains it, but please consider googling your question yourselves before asking here.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for converting your comment into an answer.

Comment: No problem, didn't have time for full answer when I posted the comment and then the question was put on hold. I saw the hold was removed, so I did the answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of accomplishing this is to create an **Automator** *Quick Action*  with a **Run Shell Script** *action*, using `screencapture` with the `-C` *option* and assign it the **⇧⌘3** *keyboard shortcut*, after unchecking it for **[] Save picture of screen as a file** in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Screen Shots**

The image below shows the **Automator** *Quick Action*  with a **Run Shell Script** *action*, its *settings* and the `screencapture` *command* formatted to produce the **macOS** *default naming* as on a **US English** install with the **Region** set to **United States**. This of course can be modified to suit ones own needs/wants.

The following command:

```
screencapture -C "$HOME/Desktop/$(date "+Screen Shot %Y-%m-%d% at %H.%M.%S %p.png")"
```

Creates a **PNG** image on the **Desktop**, named as in this example:

```
Screen Shot 2019-06-03 at 3.45.30 PM.png
```

[image: Automator Quick Action]

Before assigning the e.g. **Full Screen Shot Including Mouse** (Quick Action) the **⇧⌘3** *keyboard shortcut*, first uncheck it for **[] Save picture of screen as a file** in: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Screen Shots**

Then in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, give the e.g., **Full Screen Shot Including Mouse** the **⇧⌘3** *keyboard shortcut*.

Note: Sometimes a newly created **Automator** *Quick Action*, which has been assigned a *keyboard shortcut*, doesn't trigger the first time the *keyboard shortcut* is pressed. If this occurs, usually triggering the *Quick Action* by the **Services** menu will enable the *keyboard shortcut* to work going forward.

---

If you want a different *image format* for the saved *screen shot*, you'll need to use the `−t`  *option*. For a JPEG image use, e.g.:

```
screencapture -C -t jpg "$HOME/Desktop/$(date "+Screen Shot %Y-%m-%d% at %H.%M.%S %p.jpg")"
```

See the *manual page* for `screencapture` for additional information.

The *filename* uses the `date` *command* within *command substitution* `$(...)` which allows the *output* of a *command* to replace it. See the Command Substitution section in the `bash` manual page for additional information.

See the *manual pages* for the `date` *command* and `strftime` Standard C Library for additional information and an understanding of the *operand* used to format the *date* and *time* portion of the *filename* produced within the *command substitution*.

Hint: An easy and more user friendly way to show the *manual page* for any given *command* is to, in Terminal, type the *command* and then right-click on it, selecting: Open man Page